# Google Gmail API - regular or service account

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-workspace, service-accounts

We are developing an internal application in `.NET Core 3.1`. One of the requirements is that all users of the application must be able to see number of messages in predefined Gmail account (ex. `test@company.com`) which is part of GSuite. This means that every user who logs into the application is able to see this information, without any additional Google sign-in or anything similar. Application should be able to access the emails without user interaction, using just the code.

Upon reading the documentation, I noticed that there are two types of accounts - regular and service account. I have the following questions:

1. Which account type is suitable for our scenario? I am leaning towards service account.
2. What do I need to do to be able to access emails from `test@company.com`? Do I need to log into this account, enable Gmail API, create service account, download credentials and use them in our application? Does Gsuite administrator need to do anything else?
3. Do service accounts work for non-GSuite emails? I want to test the code on random account which I created (ex. `abc123@gmail.com`)?

Answer (score 1):

You will need the gsuite admin to set up domain wide delegation for your service account to be able to access the email accounts of the users on the domain. Service accounts do not work with non gsuite domain emails.

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(serviceAccountCredentialFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
      credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(scopes);
      }
```

Comment: Should admin (`admin@company.com`) create a service account or is it okay that it is created from `test@company.com` account? Can I restrict service account to only be able to access emails from `test@company.com`?

Comment: You can create the service account.  The admin will need to give you domain wide delegation.  You will have access to all emails to the domain there is no way for them to limit it.

Comment: Can admin at least limit what actions can be done by service account? For example, can he/she disable deleting emails?

Comment: No Service account gives full access to emails on the domain, all users.

Comment: Provided that we want to display information about emails in `test@company.com` inbox to all users of our application without them having to log in with Google, is service account the only option?

Comment: If the user is the owner of test@company.com email address you cold have them login to their own account and access the data that way.  Otherwise the only way to access information about a gsuite gmail account without the user logging in would be to use a service account.    Tip: You should also consider the cost of verifying an application using gmail scopes.  Its is also lengthy process you might want to start looking into it now.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by your last two sentences? Can you provide any link which explains the process of verifying an application?

Comment: @Mark `Can admin at least limit what actions can be done by service account? For example, can he/she disable deleting emails?` Yes, the actions that can be done by a service account are limited by what scopes you specify when setting up the domain-wide delegation (see step 5 [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)). And the service account will have access to whatever data the impersonated account has access to. Take a good look at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority.